# Build Error on apple silicon M1 with docker

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu-18.04, apple-silicon

I was trying to dockerize a flask application with a third-party cli (plastimatch) on my M1. 
I used ubuntu:18.04 as base image. The build on more recent version would fail with the error message 'no installation candidate was found'. The first odd thing I noticed was that the exact same build would succeed on a linux server.

I used a local venv to finalize the application and as I started to dockerize everything I got the following error:

> #16 22.37   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. 
> #16 22.37   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pylibjpeg-libjpeg 
> #16 22.37 Failed to build pylibjpeg-openjpeg pylibjpeg-libjpeg
> #16 22.37 ERROR: Could not build wheels for pylibjpeg-openjpeg, pylibjpeg-libjpeg, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

These python packages are wrappers for different C++ libaries, that handle images. The local build fails and the build on our linux server runs perfectly fine.

Has anyone noticed similar problems when dockerizing there applications locally in development? And are there any solutions to it?

Here is the reference of the used Dockerfile and requirements.txt (currently missing specific versions):

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base

RUN  apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get install -y python3.8 python3-pip
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3 && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3

RUN apt-get install -y \
    plastimatch \
    zlib1g \
    cmake

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

FROM base as upload-dev
RUN echo "Building dev version"
COPY requirements_dev.txt requirements_dev.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements_dev.txt
COPY . .
```

```
python-dotenv
cython
pynrrd
flask-cors
Flask
Werkzeug
httplib2
numpy
pydicom
highdicom
dicomweb-client
```

## Update: 01. July 2022

I could track down the error.
The problem was the missing wheel of some third party libraries. If no wheel could be located, the source code will be fetched and installed by a compiler. This crashed on my machine during the installation of libraries that use C++ at their core.
An easy approach to fix this problem would be to directly use the linux AMD64 image.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 $YOUR_BASE_IMAGE
```

This would be a bit slower but for most development environments sufficient.
A detailed explanation: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-problems-mac/

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to install Rosetta 2, which is included in the Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#system-requirements

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```